# i am using phonegap and i have added local notification plugin in a project but whenever i build my project it shows this error

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

```
 executing 'cordova build android'...
cp: no such file or directory: D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\www\res\icon\ios\icon-72.png


cp: no such file or directory: D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\www\res\icon\ios\icon-72-2x.png


Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""

ANDROID_HOME=D:\Softwares\Phonegap (32 bit)\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

Running: D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

:preBuild

:compileDebugNdk
 UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:compileLint

:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies

:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
 UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies

:compileDebugAidl


:compileDebugRenderscript


:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets

:generateDebugResValues
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources


:processDebugManifest


:processDebugResources


:generateDebugSources


:compileDebugJava
D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\notification\Options.java:245: error: cannot find symbol

            return NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                                     ^

  symbol:   variable DEFAULT_LIGHTS

  location: class NotificationCompat

D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\notification\Options.java:262: error: cannot find symbol

            return NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT;

                                     ^

  symbol:   variable COLOR_DEFAULT

  location: class NotificationCompat

D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\notification\Builder.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
                .setColor(options.getColor())
                ^
  symbol:   method setColor(int)
  location: class Builder

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

 FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.947 secs


D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\sumit\phonegapApp\liveProject\HZT\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, than i removed the plugin and added and older version and it worked
ionic plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification@0.7.8